initialization of boost::flyweights::intermodule_holder fails with interprocess_exception and permission denied
I've no clue why this would fail.
The shared_memory_object should be unique as it is only accessed from within the same process.
The current directory is writable and so is $TMPDIR and so is /tmp/
Here comes the stacktrace:
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x99ca40,
    tinfo=0x946668 <typeinfo for boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception>,
    dest=0x5a0f8a <boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception::~interprocess_exception()>)
    at ../../../../gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
(gdb) where
#0  __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x99ca40, tinfo=0x946668 <typeinfo for boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception>,
    dest=0x5a0f8a <boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception::~interprocess_exception()>)
    at ../../../../gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:62
#1  0x00000000005a5261 in boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create<char> (this=0x7fffffffa200,
    type=boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::DoOpen, filename=0x99c930 "bip.gmem.map.44132_0.000000", mode=boost::interprocess::read_write,
    perm=...) at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp:425
#2  0x00000000005a1e7d in boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::shared_memory_object (this=0x7fffffffa200,
    name=0x99c930 "bip.gmem.map.44132_0.000000", mode=boost::interprocess::read_write)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp:84
#3  0x00000000005aa28b in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::managed_open_or_create_impl<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, 16ul, true, false>::priv_open_or_create<char const*, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_open_func<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_memory_impl<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0ul>, 0ul>, boost::interprocess::iset_index, 16ul> > > (this=0x7fffffffa3d8,
    type=boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::DoOpen, id=@0x7fffffffa340: 0x99c930 "bip.gmem.map.44132_0.000000", size=0,
    mode=boost::interprocess::read_write, addr=0x0, perm=..., construct_func=...)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp:488
#4  0x00000000005a7630 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::managed_open_or_create_impl<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, 16ul, true, false>::managed_open_or_create_impl<char const*, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_open_func<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_memory_impl<char, boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_mutex_family, boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void, long, unsigned long, 0ul>, 0ul>, boost::interprocess::iset_index, 16ul> > > (this=0x7fffffffa3d8,
    id=@0x7fffffffa340: 0x99c930 "bip.gmem.map.44132_0.000000", mode=boost::interprocess::read_write, addr=0x0, construct_func=...)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_open_or_create_impl.hpp:179
#5  0x00000000005a552a in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true>::basic_managed_global_memory (this=0x7fffffffa3d0, name=0x99c930 "bip.gmem.map.44132_0.000000", addr=0x0)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/managed_global_memory.hpp:108
#6  0x00000000005a26bf in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_helpers::thread_safe_global_map_dependant<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::apply_gmem_erase_logic (
    filepath=0x99c8e0 "/tmp/boost_interprocess/gmem/lck44132_0.000000", filename=0x994923 "lck44132_0.000000")
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/portable_intermodule_singleton.hpp:171
#7  0x00000000005a57a8 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::for_each_file_in_dir<void (*)(char const*, char const*)> (
    dir=0x994840 "/tmp/boost_interprocess/gmem",
    f=0x5a25e7 <boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_helpers::thread_safe_global_map_dependant<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::apply_gmem_erase_logic(char const*, char const*)>)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/os_file_functions.hpp:804
#8  0x00000000005a283d in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_helpers::thread_safe_global_map_dependant<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::remove_old_gmem ()
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/portable_intermodule_singleton.hpp:198
#9  0x00000000005b9eab in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_common<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::initialize_global_map_handle ()
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/intermodule_singleton_common.hpp:237
#10 0x00000000005b588f in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_common<boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::initialize_singleton_logic (ptr=@0x97ba80: 0x0,
    this_module_singleton_initialized=@0x97ba88: 1,
    constructor=0x5b59e7 <boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_impl<boost::flyweights::detail::flyweight_core<boost::flyweights::detail::default_value_policy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, mpl_::na, boost::flyweights::refcounted, boost::flyweights::hashed_factory<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, 0>, boost::flyweights::no_locking, boost::flyweights::intermodule_holder>::holder_arg, true, false, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::singleton_constructor(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true>&)>, phoenix=false) at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/intermodule_singleton_common.hpp:127
#11 0x00000000005b21e2 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_impl<boost::flyweights::detail::flyweight_core<boost::flyweights::detail::default_value_policy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, mpl_::na, boost::flyweights::refcounted, boost::flyweights::hashed_factory<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, 0>, boost::flyweights::no_locking, boost::flyweights::intermodule_holder>::holder_arg, true, false, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::atentry_work () at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/intermodule_singleton_common.hpp:345
#12 0x00000000005aee02 in boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::intermodule_singleton_impl<boost::flyweights::detail::flyweight_core<boost::flyweights::detail::default_value_policy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, mpl_::na, boost::flyweights::refcounted, boost::flyweights::hashed_factory<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, 0>, boost::flyweights::no_locking, boost::flyweights::intermodule_holder>::holder_arg, true, false, boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::basic_managed_global_memory<boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object, true> >::get () at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/interprocess/detail/intermodule_singleton_common.hpp:335
#13 0x00000000005aaf81 in boost::flyweights::detail::flyweight_core<boost::flyweights::detail::default_value_policy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, mpl_::na, boost::flyweights::refcounted, boost::flyweights::hashed_factory<mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, 0>, boost::flyweights::no_locking, boost::flyweights::intermodule_holder>::init ()
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/flyweight/detail/flyweight_core.hpp:112
#14 0x000000000059de56 in __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__initialize_p=1, __priority=65535)
    at /mnt/share/boost/boost-1.80//include/boost/flyweight/detail/flyweight_core.hpp:278
#15 0x000000000059f46b in _GLOBAL__sub_I_messagehandler.cc(void) () at src/framework/src/messagehandler.cc:2516
#16 0x00000000007fe79d in __libc_csu_init ()
#17 0x00002aaaabbbf4e5 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#18 0x00000000005901ae in _start ()

The file in question /tmp/boost_interprocess/gmem/lck44132_0.000000 (shown in the stacktrace) belonged to another user. It might be the case that process IDs have restarted. But the number recorded in the filename does not match the process ID 38193.

The problem is that the process in question might crash or get killed. Since there is no structured signal handling on LINUX, there is nothing useful one can do in this case. So a file (shared memory segment) created by this library might get left in the system and cause a subsequent process (from another user) to fail. Another problem is of course that the shared memory object persists even if no process has it open.
